# ECONNREFUSED for Postgres on nodeJS with dockers

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

I'm building an app running on NodeJS using postgresql.
I'm using SequelizeJS as ORM.
To avoid using real postgres daemon and having nodejs on my own device, i'm using containers with docker-compose.

when I run `docker-compose up`
it starts the pg database

```
database system is ready to accept connections
```

and the nodejs server.
but the server can't connect to database.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.01:5432
```

If I try to run the server without using containers (with real nodejs and postgresd on my machine) it works.

But I want it to work correctly with containers. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

here is the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
web:
  image: node
  command: npm start
  ports:
    - "8000:4242"
  links:
    - db
  working_dir: /src
  environment:
    SEQ_DB: mydatabase
    SEQ_USER: username
    SEQ_PW: pgpassword
    PORT: 4242
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:pgpassword@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase
  volumes:
    - ./:/src
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
  - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: username
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpassword
```

Could someone help me please?

(someone who likes docker :) )

Comment: this article mentions "boot2docker ip" command, seems useful here? https://www.andreagrandi.it/2015/02/21/how-to-create-a-docker-image-for-postgresql-and-persist-data/

Comment: seems to make a difference as to which host OS you are on

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Your `DATABASE_URL` refers to `127.0.0.1`, which is the [loopback adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface) (more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it)). This means "connect to myself".

When running both applications (without using Docker) on the same host, they are both addressable on the same adapter (also known as `localhost`).

When running both applications in containers they are not both on localhost as before. Instead you need to point the `web` container to the `db` container's IP address on the `docker0` adapter - which `docker-compose` sets for you.

Change:

`127.0.0.1` to `CONTAINER_NAME` (e.g. `db`)

Example:

```
DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:pgpassword@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:pgpassword@db:5432/mydatabase
```

This works thanks to Docker links: the `web` container has a file (`/etc/hosts`) with a `db` entry pointing  to the IP that the `db` container is on. This is the first place a system (in this case, the container) will look when trying to resolve hostnames.

Comment: i am a noob/beginner with postgres/node. where exactly do i need to do the change?

Comment: @nerdess `DATABASE_URL` is in the question's `docker-compose.yml` - that's what needs changing. You reference it in your application code with `process.env['DATABASE_URL']`.

Comment: What if, on a Windows 10 machine, your Node app is running in Docker, but your Postgres is not?

Comment: @Andy changing that I get `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db db:5432`

Comment: @Dani Did you modified the `docker-compose.yml` or another file?

Comment: Adding the `database container name` from `docker-compose.yml`  as port worked for me as well. `localhost` is indeed not used when app is running on `Docker` environment. Thanks for your support.

Comment: For those of you who encountered the same issue that @Dani mentioned, make sure that your environment variables are configured corrently. For me, I'd misconfigured my Dockerfile so that Docker couldn't resolve the hostname

Comment: `docker compose build` helped my issue. `docker compose` doesn't rebuild your `Dockerfile` by default. See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1487. I was running an old build with `127.0.0.1` hardcoded.

Comment: The best answer out there. Maybe remember about adding container_name: in docker compose new versions to each container to be sure.

Comment: This also applies to having trouble connecting from the web front end container to the API container.  Once I switched the API URL in my `.env.local` to `http://api:3333` things started working again.

Answer (score 46):

For further readers, if you're using `Docker desktop for Mac` use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as it's suggested in the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds). I came across same `connection refused...` problem. Backend `api-service` couldn't connect to `postgres` using `localhost/127.0.0.1`. Below is my docker-compose.yml and environment variables as a reference:

```
version: "2"

services:
  api:
    container_name: "be"
    image: <image_name>:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: host.docker.internal
      DB_USER: <your_user>
      DB_PASS: <your_pass>
    networks: 
      - mynw

  db:
    container_name: "psql"
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: <your_postgres_db_name>
      POSTGRES_USER: <your_postgres_user>
      POSTGRES_PASS: <your_postgres_pass>
    volumes:
      - ~/dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - mynw
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer.. It worked like a charm

Comment: Been bagging my head against this for ages trying all manner of suggestions, this finally got my migrations working. Thank you.

Comment: I'm using Mac and I've been looking for this answer for almost two hours across internet, and it makes the things done, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had two containers one called postgresdb, and another call node

I changed my node queries.js from:

```js
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'users',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432,
})
```

To

```js
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'postgresdb',
    database: 'users',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432,
})
```

All I had to do was change the host to my container name ["postgresdb"] and that fixed this for me. I'm sure this can be done better but I just learned docker compose / node.js stuff in the last 2 days.

Answer (score 5):

If you send database vars separately. You can assign a database host.

```
DB_HOST=<POSTGRES_SERVICE_NAME> #in your case "db" from docker-compose file.
```

Answer (score 2):

If none of the other solutions worked for you, consider manual wrapping of `PgPool.connect()` with retry upon having ECONNREFUSED:

```
const pgPool = new Pool(pgConfig);
const pgPoolWrapper = {
    async connect() {
        for (let nRetry = 1; ; nRetry++) {
            try {
                const client = await pgPool.connect();
                if (nRetry > 1) {
                    console.info('Now successfully connected to Postgres');
                }
                return client;
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.toString().includes('ECONNREFUSED') && nRetry < 5) {
                    console.info('ECONNREFUSED connecting to Postgres, ' +
                        'maybe container is not ready yet, will retry ' + nRetry);
                    // Wait 1 second
                    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

(See [this issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1789) in node-postgres for tracking.)

Comment: Literally nothing worked until I tried this and it instantly worked! Thank You!!!!

Comment: For people coming to this error from Stephen Grider course of Docker, use this after PGClient connection in the server's index.js file. It works

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

> Each container can now look up the hostname `web` or `db` and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, `web`’s application code could connect to the URL `postgres://db:5432` and start using the Postgres database.

> It is important to note the distinction between `HOST_PORT` and `CONTAINER_PORT`. In the above example, for `db`, the `HOST_PORT` is `8001` and the container port is `5432` (postgres default). Networked service-to-service communication uses the `CONTAINER_PORT`. When `HOST_PORT` is defined, the service is accessible outside the swarm as well.

> Within the `web` container, your connection string to `db` would look like `postgres://db:5432`, and from the host machine, the connection string would look like `postgres://{DOCKER_IP}:8001`.

So `DATABASE_URL` should be `postgres://username:pgpassword@db:5432/mydatabase`

Comment: Can't believe i was hours trying to find the problem and this was the perfect answear, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I am here with a tiny modification about handle this.

As [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114770/andy) say in him response.

- "you need to point the `web` container to the `db` container's"

And taking in consideration the official documentation about [docker-compose link's](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links)

- "Links are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name."

Because of that, you can keep your docker_compose.yml in this way:

**docker_compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
      image: node
      command: npm start
      ports:
         - "8000:4242"
      # links:
      #   - db
      working_dir: /src
      environment:
        SEQ_DB: mydatabase
        SEQ_USER: username
        SEQ_PW: pgpassword
        PORT: 4242
        # DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:pgpassword@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase
        DATABASE_URL: "postgres://username:pgpassword@db:5432/mydatabase"
      volumes:
          - ./:/src
    db:
      image: postgres
      ports:
          - "5432:5432"
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: username
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpassword
```

But it is a kinda cool way to be verbose while we are coding. So, your approach it is nice.

Answer (score -1):

I was walking through page to find the solution of my problem, and this was the solution that I found:

Change this:

```
  db:
image: postgres:14.1-alpine
container_name: doca_db
ports:
  - "54320:5432" <---------- HERE
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
volumes: 
  - psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
```

to this:

```
  db:
image: postgres:14.1-alpine
container_name: doca_db
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
volumes: 
  - psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
```