# Minimal production setup for Nest.js + Postgres + Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

Searching the solution for [How to search the exact cause "[TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database." error in NestJS + TypeORM + Docker case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74410210/how-to-search-the-exact-cause-typeormmodule-unable-to-connect-to-the-database), I has been recommended to check [ECONNREFUSED for Postgres on nodeJS with dockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357567/econnrefused-for-postgres-on-nodejs-with-dockers) topics. First that I noticed is the production setup of Posgres/TypeORM is different from local development one by not only values but also by adding of extra properties.

In my case, below setup works fine locally:

```js
import { Module as NestJS_Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModule as TypeORM_Module } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import type { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import ConfigurationRepresentative from "./Configuration/ConfigurationRepresentative";

@NestJS_Module({
  imports: [
    TypeORM_Module.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
      type: "postgres",
      host: "localhost",
      port: 5432,
      username: "postgres",
      password: "pass1234"
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: ConfigurationRepresentative.isLocalExecutionEnvironment
      })
    }),
  ]
})
export default class NestJS_ApplicationRootModule {}
```

herewith, the **docker-compose.yml** for the local development case is:

```js
version: "3"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: LocalDatabase
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

    volumes:
      - DataBaseData:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  DataBaseData:
    driver: local
```

The preset from [ECONNREFUSED for Postgres on nodeJS with dockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357567/econnrefused-for-postgres-on-nodejs-with-dockers) is

```yaml
web:
  image: node
  command: npm start
  ports:
    - "8000:4242"
  links:
    - db
  working_dir: /src
  environment:
    SEQ_DB: mydatabase
    SEQ_USER: username
    SEQ_PW: pgpassword
    PORT: 4242
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:pgpassword@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase
  volumes:
    - ./:/src
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
  - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: username
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpassword
```

Is there something that we can safely remove?
I suppose:

- The `mydatabase` already has been defined in `SEQ_DB`. Why we need to duplicate it in `DATABASE_URL`?
- Same for `SEQ_USER` and `SEQ_PW`.
- Why we need to explicitly define the `DATABASE_URL`? Could not it be computed automatically?

Currently, my **docker-compose.yaml** for the production is:

```
version: "3"

services:

  node_js:

    container_name: FrontServer
    build: .
    ports: [ "3000:3000" ]
    depends_on: [ "database" ]

  database:

    container_name: Database

    image: postgres
    ports: [ "5432:5432" ]

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass1234
      # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD} It should work too but first I need to connect

    volumes:
      - Database:/data/example.com

volumes:
  Database: {}
```

Also, how `TypeORM_Module.forRootAsync` will change?
I suppose, it will be different host (`db` instead of `localhost`?), of course, different password and some extra options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something that we can safely remove? I suppose:
> The mydatabase already has been defined in SEQ_DB. Why we need to duplicate it in DATABASE_URL?
> Same for SEQ_USER and SEQ_PW.
> Why we need to explicitly define the DATABASE_URL? Could not it be computed automatically?

As you copied this from an example, I think it shows you both options you can use, depending on your code. As both are valid options but normally are not used combined. Some people prefer to use a database URL to connect to the database, some prefer single variables. You can decide, though you also should use the same method in development.

Some companies only consider the password a secret, some also the username and some even the hostname. The more parts are seen as a secret, the more since it makes to use the database URL, as then you simply make the whole thing a single secret instead of 3 secrets.

Also on bigger projects, that have for example 50 configuration variables, you might want to consider reducing them and combine the connection to the database.

> Also, how TypeORM_Module.forRootAsync will change? I suppose, it will be different host (db instead of localhost?), of course, different password and some extra options.

Almost right. In your production docker-compose.yaml you are calling the service `database` not `db`. Therefore, you need to change `localhost` with `database`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In my case, `SEQ_DB` ,`SEQ_USER`, `DATABASE_URL` was not required. Also, your last directions ("Therefor, you need to change...") saved my day.